# Zener Diode - Vz0

Tags: voltage-regulator, diodes, zener

Theoretically, what is the importance of Vz0 in the following figure. When modeling the zener diode, why is Vz0 used over the diode's given Vz?

[image: figure from book]

For modeling, I was given the formula Vz = Vz0 + rz*Iz.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are varying degrees of accuracy that you can expect from a model. The simplest usable model of a Zener diode might pass no current for V < Vz and always drop Vz for any current more than zero.

That model is inadequate for many purposes. The next simplest model is piece wise linear, so you need two voltages, or a voltage and a slope. I think it makes more sense to think about it being linearized about Vz as you suggest, but any way you do it defines a straight line. If the model is accurate it should yield Vz at the specified test current.

For example, take the [1N4742](http://www.mccsemi.com/up_pdf/1N4728-1N4761%28DO-41G%29.pdf). It has a Vz of 12V at 21mA and a 9 ohm Zzt at 21mA. 
V0 is 12V - 21mA * 9 ohms or 11.81V. So from your formula Vz' = 11.81 + 9\$\Omega\cdot I_Z \$. At 21ma, we'd have 12V, as it should be.

Note that this linearized model will be horribly wrong if you go too far from the operating point. The value of Zzt for 0.25mA is 700 ohms, almost two orders of magnitude higher.

The suggested method allows you to use the Zener impedance from the data sheet directly, which might be convenient, and from which V0 can be calculated using Vz and the test current.

Using this model you can predict output voltage load regulation, line regulation and attenuation of input ripple (really the same as line regulation).

Comment: So for modeling, is Vz0 the voltage around the operating point? My issue is that, when analyzing a voltage shunt regulator, the voltage used to represent the voltage across the diode is Vz0 (used in circuit analysis equations), yet they specify the diode's Vz, and I cant seem to figure out why Vz0 is so important.

Comment: (As Alfred said) it's the *intercept*, which is a totally artificial point that you get when you extrapolate the slope linearized around the nominal operating point to zero current. There's no physical meaning to it other than that, but it makes the equation convenient. A more physically meaningful model would be Vz' = Vz + (Iz-I0)*Zzt, and it's only accurate for |Iz - Io| small.

Answer (score 3):

It's quite simple actually.  As you write, in the region of interest, the *linearized model* for the voltage across the zener is

$$v_Z(i_Z) = V_{Z0} + r_Z \cdot I_Z$$

Thus, when \$i_Z = 0\$,

$$v_Z(0) = V_{Z0} + r_Z \cdot 0 = V_{Z0}$$

In other words, \$V_{Z0}\$ is the voltage intercept for the *linearized model* of the Zener diode in the breakdown region.

Note carefully the use of the phrase "linearized model".

Essentially, this just entails *finding the slope of the IV curve at the operating point \$Q\$ and linearizing about that point*.

So, for different operating points, you'll have different values for \$r_Z\$ and \$V_{Z0}\$.